# Why is nginx returning a 200 page without having that domain configured?

Tags: linux, nginx

I'm using nginx and I follow a simple tutorial to create vhosts. My problem is that if someone point his DNS to my server, nginx seems to not care about the `server_name` directive.

I have:

```
  listen          80;
  server_name     www.domain.com;
```

I only have ONE vhost. If I set the DNS of `example.com` to my server, nginx responds with a 200 page! How is it possible? I don't have that vhost configured on my server.

How do I ONLY allow the domains I have configured into `server { }`?

I'm using **nginx version 0.7.67** on Ubuntu *Maverick*.

Answer (score 0):

Is it not like apache and just pick the default (first) configuration? If you don't want people to forward their domain to your server, make two or more virtual hosts, the first one pointing to an error page, and then any request for a domain not hosted by you will return an error.

Comment: and make that first vhost a default (listen 80 default;)